# To call javascript function on selecting a value from dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

In the below code i have a searchabe dropdown on selecting a value from dropdown it should call a javascript function.I tried the below code it is not working .Pls help me to solve the issue.

```
 function report(period) {
            alert();

        } 

<editable:EditableDropDownList ID="ddlreporttype" onchange="report(this.value)"  runat="server" Style="width: 70%; height:29px"  EnableViewState="true" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlreporttype_SelectedIndexChanged" onfocus="javascript: if(this.value=='--Select--'){this.value='';}" AutoselectFirstItem="true" onblur="javascript: if(this.value==''){this.value='--Select--';}">      

                         <asp:ListItem Text="---Select---" Value="0"></asp:ListItem>                                                 

                          <asp:ListItem Text="Product Valuation Report" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
                          <asp:ListItem Text="Material Movement Report" Value="2"></asp:ListItem>
                           <asp:ListItem Text="Supply / Demand Report" Value="3"></asp:ListItem>
                             <asp:ListItem Text="Grn Valuation Report" Value="4"></asp:ListItem>

                        </editable:EditableDropDownList>
```

Comment: @Mairaj Ahmad I want to call js fn on dropdown selection change

Comment: so onchange is not working ?

Comment: @Mairaj Ahmad yes onchange not working

Answer (score 2):

Did you put the script part in a Script tag?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            function report(period) {
                alert("test");

            }

        </script>
```

if not please do

Answer (score 1):

try this code:

```
 $("#ddlreporttype").change(function () {
            alert($(this).val());
        });
```

Comment: Please try this one : 
$(document).on('change', '#ddlreporttype', function () { alert($(this).val()); });

Answer (score 0):

Try the following,

a. Put the report function under script tag,

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function report(period) {
            alert();
        }
</script>
```

b. call the report method as shown below,

```
<editable:EditableDropDownList ID="ddlreporttype" onchange="javascript:report(this.value)"
```